# SQL Sum in subquery

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query using tables that use key values to store fields.  I want to retrieve a list of Events based on a date criteria and status and return the common fields (Event Id, Event Name, In Date, Out Date...) and also a sum of rent values that are in a table that needs to be summed per event as the rent in entered by specific rooms included.  I can get the table to sum the values but it repeats the common fields rather than just showing one line per event.  In the picture below, I would just like one row instead of repeating the same values for every room that was returned in the SUM.  I have a feeling this is too specific for anyone to be able to help, but I don't know how to do it.

```
    SELECT ATxt.RootKey AS EventId, ATxt.FldValue AS EventName, ARange.FldValue AS StartDate, ARange.FldValue2 AS EndDate, 
CASE 
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 1 THEN 'Contracted'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 2 THEN 'Definite'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 3 THEN 'Inquiry'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 4 THEN 'BCC Hold'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 5 THEN 'Tentative 1st Option'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 6 THEN 'Tentative 2nd Option'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 7 THEN 'Cancel'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 8 THEN 'Prospect '
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 9 THEN 'Definite Visit Baltimore'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 10 THEN 'Cancel with Contract'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 11 THEN '1st Tentative Noise'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 12 THEN 'Definite Noise'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 13 THEN 'Contracted Noise'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 14 THEN '2nd Tentative Noise'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 15 THEN '3rd Tentative Noise'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 16 THEN '1st Tentative Quiet'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 17 THEN '2nd Tentative Quiet'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 18 THEN '3rd Tentative Quiet'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 19 THEN 'Definite Quiet'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 20 THEN 'Contracted Quiet'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 21 THEN 'Tentative GrandFathered'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 22 THEN 'Definite GrandFathered'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 23 THEN 'Contracted GrandFathered'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 24 THEN 'Inquiry 2'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 25 THEN 'Sales & Marketing Event Hold'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 26 THEN 'Inquiry 3'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 27 THEN 'Addendum'
    WHEN ANum.FldValue = 28 THEN 'Covid19 Cancels'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
END AS BookingStatus, ANum2.FldValue AS SalesPersonKey, ATxt2.FldValue AS SalesPersonFirst, ATxt3.FldValue AS SalesPersonLast, 
AAmt2.FldValue AS Utilities, AAmt3.FldValue AS Sound, AAmt4.FldValue AS Misc, AAmt5.FldValue AS FoodBeverage, AAmt6.FldValue AS Telecom, AAmt7.FldValue AS IATSE,
    (SELECT SUM(AAmt.FldValue) 
    FROM AppAmt AS AAmt
    WHERE ATxt.RootKey = AAmt.RootKey AND AAmt.AppKey = 4 AND AAmt.ObjKey = 30003 AND AAmt.FldKey = 30019) AS TotalRent
FROM AppTxt AS ATxt
--FldKey = 30002 (Event Name), FldKey = 30005 (Booking Status Code), FldKey = 300020 (Sales Person), FldKey = 30048 (Start / End Date)
INNER JOIN AppRange AS ARange
    ON ATxt.RootKey = ARange.RootKey AND (ARange.AppKey = 4 AND ARange.ObjKey = 30001 AND ARange.FldKey = 30048 AND ARange.FldValue2 >= '2013-07-01' AND ARange.FldValue2 <= '2014-06-30')
INNER JOIN AppNum AS ANum
--Only retrieve Events with Status matching those included in the Sales Forecasting export
    ON ATxt.RootKey = ANum.RootKey AND (ANum.AppKey = 4 AND ANum.ObjKey = 30001 AND ANum.FldKey = 30005 AND ANum.FldValue IN (1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 28))
INNER JOIN AppAmt AS AAmt
    ON ATxt.RootKey = AAmt.RootKey AND (AAmt.AppKey = 4 AND AAmt.ObjKey = 30003 AND AAmt.FldKey = 30019)
INNER JOIN AppNum AS ANum2
    ON ATxt.RootKey = ANum2.RootKey AND (ANum2.AppKey = 4 AND ANum2.ObjKey = 30001 AND Anum2.FldKey = 30020)
--Retrieve First Name and Last Name
INNER JOIN AppTxt AS ATxt2
    ON ANum2.FldValue = ATxt2.RootKey AND (ATxt2.AppKey = 2 AND ATxt2.ObjKey = 30001 AND ATxt2.FldKey = 30004)
    INNER JOIN AppTxt AS ATxt3
    ON ANum2.FldValue = ATxt3.RootKey AND (ATxt3.AppKey = 2 AND ATxt3.ObjKey = 30001 AND ATxt3.FldKey = 30005)
--FldKey = 13 (Final Rent - Not being entered so commenting this out - use "Sales Forecast Total Rent.sql" to retrieve Total Rent and then use Excel or Python to merge with this data)
--LEFT JOIN AppAmt AS AAmt
    --ON ATxt.RootKey = AAmt.RootKey AND (ARange.AppKey = 4 AND ARange.ObjKey = 30001 AND ARange.FldKey = 13)
--FldKey = 5 (Utilities)
LEFT JOIN AppAmt AS AAmt2
    ON ATxt.RootKey = AAmt2.RootKey AND (AAmt2.AppKey = 4 AND AAmt2.ObjKey = 30001 AND AAmt2.FldKey = 5)
--FldKey = 6 (Sound)
LEFT JOIN AppAmt AS AAmt3
    ON ATxt.RootKey = AAmt3.RootKey AND (AAmt3.AppKey = 4 AND AAmt3.ObjKey = 30001 AND AAmt3.FldKey = 6)
--FldKey = 9 (Misc)
LEFT JOIN AppAmt AS AAmt4
    ON ATxt.RootKey = AAmt4.RootKey AND (AAmt4.AppKey = 4 AND AAmt4.ObjKey = 30001 AND AAmt4.FldKey = 9)
--FldKey = 10 (FoodAndBeverage)
LEFT JOIN AppAmt AS AAmt5
    ON ATxt.RootKey = AAmt5.RootKey AND (AAmt5.AppKey = 4 AND AAmt5.ObjKey = 30001 AND AAmt5.FldKey = 10)
--FldKey = 11 (Telecom)
LEFT JOIN AppAmt AS AAmt6
    ON ATxt.RootKey = AAmt6.RootKey AND (AAmt6.AppKey = 4 AND AAmt6.ObjKey = 30001 AND AAmt6.FldKey = 11)
--FldKey = 12 (IATSE)
LEFT JOIN AppAmt AS AAmt7
    ON ATxt.RootKey = AAmt7.RootKey AND (AAmt7.AppKey = 4 AND AAmt7.ObjKey = 30001 AND AAmt7.FldKey = 11)
WHERE ATxt.AppKey = 4 AND ATxt.ObjKey = 30001 AND ATxt.FldKey = 30002  --AND FldValue > 0
GROUP BY  ATxt.RootKey, ARange.FldValue, ATxt.FldValue, ARange.FldValue2, ANum.FldValue, AAmt.FldValue, ANum2.FldValue, ATxt2.FldValue, Atxt3.FldValue, AAmt2.FldValue, AAmt3.FldValue, 
AAmt4.FldValue, AAmt5.FldValue, AAmt6.FldValue, AAmt7.FldValue
--GROUP BY ATxt.RootKey
ORDER BY ARange.FldValue2
```

[image: Results returned]

Comment: oracle/sql server/mysql/..... ? add more tag to your question. i have the feeling this is sql server, but not sure

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  But I solved this by just adding a DISTINCT statement to the first value in the Select statement.